# Does the pronunciation of "is" change when we do the contraction?

Tags: pronunciation

Ok, see these 2 sentences:

**It is over** `/ɪdɪzoʊ.vɚ/` but

**It's over** `/ɪtsoʊ.vɚ/`. `'s` will be pronounced as `/s/` because it stands after a voiceless consonant

**He's over sixty**  `/hizoʊ.vɚsɪk.sti/`. `'s` will be pronounced as `/z/` because it stands after a vowel which is voiced.

However, I feel that some people just say `/ɪtzoʊ.vɚ/` **It's over**?? Maybe I am wrong??? but most of the time I hear people say like that??

Comment: The preceding letter plays a big part in this. *T*, *D*, *M*, etc. tend to turn the *S* into a *Z*. See: Palms, Darts, Errands. But *L*, etc.  preserves the *S* sound fairly well.

Comment: @lurker, are you a native? T is vioceless so s-->/s/; D,M,L are voiced so s-->/z/. That is what I learned in school. I am not a native though

Comment: S *should* -> /s/. But once you introduce regional dialects...

Comment: The question is not the proper pronunciation of the contraction; the OP knows that. However, he hears other people say it not according to the rules he sees.

Comment: Also, "it is over" is not /ɪdɪzoʊ.vɚ/, but /ɪtɪzoʊ.vɚ/, with the American English version [ɪɾɪzoʊ.vɚ] making it sound like a standard D sound.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel that some people just say `/ɪtzoʊ.vɚ/` **It's over**?? Maybe I am wrong??? but most of the time I hear people say like that??

No, it does not become /ɪ**tz**oʊ.vɚ/. The cluster */-tz/ (/t/ and /z/ in the same syllable) is impermissible in English and can be difficult to pronounce because both the obstruents--/t/ and /z/--disagree in voicing and human vocal tract is designed in such a way that obstruents that disagree in voicing are hard to pronounce, because switching from voiceless to voiced consonants (and vice versa) requires independent movement of the larynx, which can be difficult to switch on and off at the millisecond timing required for consonant clusters.

The reason why you hear *[ɪtz] is that it's not actually contracted, but there's an intervening vowel in *[ɪtz] i.e. most people pronounce it [ɪt**ɪ**z] so the vowel breaks the impermissible cluster */tz/ into [ɪt] and [ɪz], thereby making it easier to pronounce both the /t/ and /z/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the **pronunciation changes** when using a contraction.
The **sounding** is more like **the plural** of a noun than two distinct words.  For example

**with a noun**

> one rabbit
>   two rabbit**s**

**with a contraction**

> **one he
>
>   two he's**
>
> **one she
>
>   two she's**

Another example is

> **its**
>   **it's**

both sound alike, the **difference** can only be **determined through context** when speaking

Comment: How does this address the OP's question "I feel that seem people just say /ɪtzoʊ.vɚ/ It's over?? Maybe I am wrong??? but most of the time I hear people say like that??"?